# ViewPager - error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-support-library

i am trying to create a View pager on a simple activity not Fragment, But I am getting lots of errors :

I have tried to import the v4 library but I am getting these errors messages

- The import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager conflicts with a type defined in the same file
  -Cannot cast from View to ViewPager

  ```
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; **ERROR TEXT = The import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager conflicts with a type defined in the same file**

  public class ViewPager extends ActionBarActivity {

      public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

      ImageView imageView;
      ImageLoader imageLoader;
      ViewPager viewPager;
      Intent intent;
      Bundle bundle;




      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);
          Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");




          imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ViewPager.this);


          //Setting Up ViewPager
          viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager); **EEROR TEXT = Cannot cast from View to ViewPager**
          ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
          viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
          viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos)
  ```

  ;

Comment: viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos) may be problem in this line what is "pos" in your code

Answer (score 3):

Your defined class should be another class name not "ViewPager". For Example : it may be MyViewPager